# MPD permission denied when using sshfs - how to change permissions?

Tags: linux, fuse, sshfs

I am trying to mount my music folder from another computer on my network using sshfs. The folder mounts correctly and I can access the files using the terminal. However, when I try to update my MPD library using ncmpcpp I get a permission denied error in mpd.log. When the filesystem is not mounted to the music folder is can be accessed by mpd. What can I do to the folder so that mpd can see it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPD is probably not running under the same user account that you used to mount the sshfs filesystem.

See the [FUSE FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_don.27t_other_users_have_access_to_the_mounted_filesystem.3F) and the [sshfs FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=SshfsFaq#Mounting_as_root), then if you're comfortable with the security risks add the `user_allow_other` option to `/etc/fuse.conf` and the `-o allow_other` option to the mount command.